# Twilio with Silent Network Authentication

Tags: twilio, sna

Would like to know any example (nodeJS) on the Silent Network Authentication feature with Twilio.

Also, can this be used to verify a local non-twilio telephone number and there by we can use the number as outgoing caller id?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same method you would use for a "regular" verification request. The only thing you need to change is the `channel` parameter:

```js
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.verify.v2.services('VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                .verifications
                .create({to: '+15017122661', channel: 'sna'})
                .then(verification => console.log(verification.sid));
```

You can find this and other snippets in the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification#start-new-verification-with-silent-network-auth).

Regarding the second question. Local numbers won't work as the SNA technology build on top of the standardized GSM (Global System for Mobile Communications) authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Let me ask one more help: Is there any way we can implement a silent caller id verification of non-twilio number without getting any inputs from the number owner ?

Comment: Twilio doesn't provide a service for this. So either you need to pull it from a user profile that you might have or you check if the native SDK of the phone provides this. But it seems that [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/9171) doesn't expose this info